# Underlining glitch

Tags: ios, uilabel, nsattributedstring, core-text, uifont

I'm trying to add underlining to an attributed text using a custom font (*HelveticaRounded-Bold*). Yet, the underlining glitches both on the Simulator and a device. Like this:

[image]

This is a `UILabel` but I can also reproduce the problem in `UITextView`. It appears as if the text renderer is miscalculating where to draw the underline, on some lines.

The bare-bones code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];
  UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaRounded-Bold" size:18];
  self.label.font = font;
  self.label.numberOfLines = 0;
  NSDictionary *attributes = @{ NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName : @(NSUnderlineStyleSingle) };
  self.label.attributedText = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"This is a test. And the test has failed. What did I do to deserve this? Why NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName? Why?"
                                                              attributes:attributes];
}
```

Fun fact: the underlining does not glitch at size 24 or above (!). It also does not repro using `TTTAttributedLabel`.

Any idea what might be going on here?

Comment: I'm seeing this issue as well. Have you found a solution for this?

Comment: I tried a font that I know to be problematic in this regard in Apple's TextEdit, and the problem occurs there, too. Bad font, I wonder?

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be a glitch on non-retina devices when using `NSUnderlineStyleThick`. Switching to `NSUnderlineStyleSingle` seems to fix the issue. So you can set up a conditional for non-retina devices to use `NSUnderlineStyleSingle` if you want to keep `NSUnderlineStyleThick` on other devices.

Edit: Just realized you're using `NSUnderlineStyleSingle` in your sample code :/ In my code, this worked for my given font/size, which is just system font. This fixed the issue on my end. So it seems that this fix may not be universal but it worked in my case.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue for UIButton on non-retina display. What I did is I just changed 'NSUnderlineStyleSingle' to 'NSUnderlineStyleDouble' for non-retina devices.

```
NSMutableAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:titleString?titleString:@"" attributes:@{ NSFontAttributeName: button.titleLabel.font}];

[buttonTitleString addAttribute:NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName value:[CommonUtil getValueForUnderlineStyle] range:NSMakeRange(0, [buttonTitleString length])];
[button.titleLabel setAttributedText:attributedString];

+ (NSNumber *)getValueForUnderlineStyle {
NSNumber *numberToReturn = @(NSUnderlineStyleSingle);
if(!(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad && [[UIScreen mainScreen] respondsToSelector:@selector(scale)] && [UIScreen mainScreen].scale > 1)) {
    // Non Retina iPad
    numberToReturn = @(NSUnderlineStyleDouble);
}
return numberToReturn;
}
```